# Persistable key value pair storage in Synapse or ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am using Synapse and have a lot of scenarios where I need to read a value at the beginning of a pipeline then save a value at the end of a pipeline as a key value pair (kvp).  e.g. when the pipeline begins I read a value from a kvp store to get the max date from the last time the pipeline ran, I use that value to get all values from a table that are greater than or equal to that datetime.  when the pipeline finishes doing what it has to do, I save the max modified date from this run.  wash, rise, dry.  I have a few ideas, like parquet file, redis (this seems a bit much). Just trying to see if anyone has come up with a more elegant/simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Global Parameters** which can be used in different pipelines and the values can be modified in the run time.

Go to `Manage` in Azure Data Factory and click on `Global Parameters` in the left panel options. Then click on `+ New`.

[image]

Create a new Global Parameter.

[image]

Later you use this global parameter in any pipeline and can change its value in runtime. Refer below image for the same.

[image]

Comment: Agreed. Good answer. But I don’t think you can save a value to a global parameter at the end of the pipeline. I would suggest writing it to a database instead.

Comment: I'm using Synapse, **Global parameters** have not made their way over there yet.  In ADF, looks like you could do it, but it's not just a simple set.  You'd have to create a REST in your ADF pipeline back to ADF, I haven't tried this.

[Global Parameters - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/global-parameters/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP)